# Signed integer overflow, intrinsics, and undefined behaviour

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, undefined-behavior, intrinsics

Is the very simple code below susceptible to undefined behaviour as the integer overflows as a result of the operation?

```cpp
static volatile LONG x = LONG_MAX;

InterlockedIncrement(&x);
```

According to the standard, signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour. However, here we are out of the standard, as we are calling compiler's intrinsic function, which inlines to some assembly. Also, the value of `x` is not used anywhere (the function is just used as a memory barrier).

An [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517070/is-sse2-signed-integer-overflow-undefined) suggests this is not UB.

Comment: I'd argue it doesn't matter when or where the overflow happens. If it happens then it's UB from the C++ standard point of view. The behavior may be defined from the point of view of the compiler and the code it generates though, but from a strict C++-standard perspective it's still UB.

Comment: The way I would look at it is: `InterlockedIncrement` still has to return a `LONG`. What value will it return in this case?

Comment: @P.W It could wrap and consequently return `LONG_MIN`, right? Just like .NET's [Interlocked.Increment()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Interlocked_Increment_System_Int32__) does.

Comment: @MatthäusBrandl The problem is that the "wrapping" is not defined by the C++ specification.

Comment: It is not terribly undefined behavior these days.  They don't build a lot of processors anymore that use one's-complement representation or trap on signed overflow.   The logic error it produces is certainly the bigger issue.  You'd of course favor MemoryBarrier() if that is all you need.

Comment: Technically undefined behavior in C++, but on x86 `LOCK inc` has well defined behavior.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: atomic operations are executed as if the number was unsigned (so atomic overflow is not UB). This is defined by the standard. But `InterlockedIncrement` is not covered by the standard, so MS doc have to be checked. But I'm pretty sure that currently this is not UB, and does what we expect: two's complement wrap on all architectures that MSVC supports.

Comment: Unfortunately, MS doc does not say anything about overflows or underflows. Perhaps it does not say anything, because there is nothing to say as the operation is perfectly safe :-)

Comment: @HansPassant: sorry about being super-picky, but it's "ones' complement" (and "two's complement") (and it is not just about number representation. Increment could saturate, for example).

Comment: @HansPassant: If GCC is given a choice between generating a machine-code program that processes e.g. `uint32a = uint16a*uint16b;` in a manner that will work for all values of the operands, or one that works more efficiently for all values whose product is smaller than `INT_MAX` but arbitrarily corrupts memory for other values, it's designed to favor the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I claim there's no UB here, neither per the language standard (the standard doesn't cover this function/intrinsic) nor per the implementation, and there's a simple rollover.

Here's my reasoning...

`InterlockedIncrement()` is conceptually very simple and if it had a special case, it would be very hard to miss it and fail to document it. And the documentation hasn't mentioned any special case here for some 15+ years.

How would you implement it anyway?

If you're on the 80486 or better, the most natural implementation uses the `XADD` instruction with the `LOCK` prefix that atomically adds a value to a memory variable. The instruction by itself does not generate any overflow exception, however it does modify the `EFLAGS` register as does the regular addition instruction, `ADD`, so it's possible to detect an overflow and act on it. Specifically, you could throw in the `INTO` instruction to turn the overflow condition into an exception. Or you could use the conditional jump instruction, `JO`, to jump the overflow handler.

If you only have 80386 features, you have `lock inc` and `lock add` which can implement `InterlockedIncrement` only if the return value isn't used except to test it for zero/non-zero or negative/non-negative, or other condition you can derive from EFLAGS such as that signed-overflow happened (EFLAGS.OF).  (In the general case where code does `int tmp = InterlockedIncrement(&shared);`, you'd need either `lock xadd` or a `lock cmpxchg` retry loop but those are both 486 or Pentium features.  So you'd need a separate lock variable which all writers acquire and release, perhaps using the `XCHG` instruction (the `LOCK` is implicit with it) to take the lock.  But this isn't compatible with the `Interlocked...` API which just exposes lock-free hardware operations, unlike `std::atomic<int>` which could have `lock_free()` be false when compiling for 386 and use a separate spinlock like it does for wide types.  (In shared memory between processes, the spinlock would also need to be in shared memory so both processes could respect the same spinlock, so a library API can't just invent one for you, and it would force even operations like `exchange` to take/release the lock.)

---

Now, would you want to throw `INTO` or `JO` into all instances of `InterlockedIncrement()`? Probably not, definitely not by default. People like their atomic operations small and fast.  And in some algorithms, there'd be no way to prevent the possibility of overflow with huge numbers of threads.

This is the "immediate" UB. What about the "creeping" UB?
If you had C code like this:

```
  int a = INT_MAX;
  if (a + 1 < a)
    puts("Overflow!");
```

You'd likely get [nothing printed](https://godbolt.org/z/6V-x-w) nowadays.
Modern compilers know that `a + 1` can't legally(!) overflow and so the condition in the if statement can be taken as false irrespective of the value of `a`.

Can you have a similar optimization with `InterlockedIncrement()`?

Well, given that the variable is `volatile` and can indeed change in a different thread at any moment, the compiler may not assume unchanged `a` from two memory reads of it (you'd likely write `a + 1 < a` or similar as multiple statements and each `a` would need to be fetched if it's volatile).

It would also be an odd context to try to make the optimization in.

Comment: From what I can tell, the Standard would allow an implementation to do anything it likes in response to `InterlockedIncrement(anything)` unless user code defines a function by that name (in which case that function should be called).  Implementations would be free to specify that such a call will behave in some useful fashion, but the Standard says nothing about what it would do.

Comment: According to http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html, the current opcode for `cmpxchg` was new with Pentium.  NASM uses `cmpxchg486` for the old `0F A7` opcode supported by some (but reportedly not all) 486 chips.  Anyway, interesting point that you *could* implement a fairly safe atomic `inc` with an `xchg` (not `cmpxchg`) retry loop, if the only write access was other increment threads.  You'd detect races (where cmpxchg would have failed) and calculate a new increment to attempt to add.  (e.g. if you actually decreased the counter by 2, you then try to add 3 next time).

Comment: But I don't think there's a way to implement `lock xadd` with just `xchg`, only `lock inc` / `lock add 1` for the right total count, without the right "old value".  It doesn't preserve the sequence of operations (some threads get a bogus old value).  Or another way to look at it, if you want the old value from the first xchg, instead of the successful xchg, is that other threads see effects of you mucking around with the counter multiple times, not one atomic modification.  If there are pure readers as well as the writers, they can see non-monotonic changes to the value.

Comment: Anyway, probably also worth pointing out that **C++ `atomic<int>` is defined by ISO C++11 to be 2's complement with overflow defined as wrap-around.**  Same for C11 `_Atomic int`.  (except that in C++, `++a` and `a += 1` are defined by the standard (and maybe in some real headers) in terms of `fetch_add(1) + 1`, possibly making that part done with plain `int`.    https://twitter.com/jfbastien/status/958026267420327936.).  InterlockedIncrement is basically an intrinsic for `lock inc/add` or `lock xadd`, (hopefully the former if the result is unused), not subject to C signed integer rules.

Comment: @PeterCordes If you can use `XCHG` to implement a spinlock, you can effectively implement any atomic operation.

Comment: Yes of course, but your answer sounded like you were describing a lock-free implementation.

Comment: @PeterCordes `InterlockedIncrement()` clearly predates C++11 with its atomics, but the latter suggests that it's a generalization of `InterlockedIncrement()` and such and standardization of common practice.

Comment: Yes that, and that current implementations are built on top of intrinsics like `InterlockedIncrement`.  Also that it would be a terrible design to have signed-overflow UB when the order of operations depends on performance details, and isn't controlled by the programmer.  (Which is why C++ standardized that but not 2's complement or signed wraparound in general.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed discussion. I'm inclined to think there is no UB, as what the `InterlockedIncrement` function does is out of the languages' scope (that is, there is no language instruction that does the increment, just some assembly instruction with predictable behaviour).

Comment: I edited your answer to clarify the situation for 386.  The previous phrasing didn't clearly state that it was talking about a separate lock, or that this would be incompatible with other threads doing volatile stores or InterlockedExchange on the shared variable itself.

Comment: Also, fun fact, `gcc -m32 -march=i386` will inline `lock inc` when you don't use the return value of C++ `fetch_add`, but calls the libatomic helper function `__atomic_fetch_add_4` when you do (https://godbolt.org/z/nP9cavb98).  IDK what implementation could be possible there, other than uniprocessor disabling interrupts.  The 32-bit libatomic.so on my system is of course built normally assuming a P6 baseline, so that function just uses `lock xadd`.  The libatomic source code (https://gitlab.com/gnutools/gcc/-/blob/trunk/libatomic/fop_n.c#L160) supports fallback to a magic `protect_start(T *)`